# Angular module-federation, is possible load some remotes as SSR and other remotes withouth using SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, webpack-module-federation

Currently we are using @angular-architects/module-federation to work with microfontend.

I was wondering if it's possible some **remote microfontend** to be loaded as SSR (necessary for the use of api keys and sensitive information) and others to be loaded without SSR.

Reading the npm documentation of [@angular-architects/module-federation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation) says..

> **Angular Universal (Server Side Rendering)**
> To make use of SSR, you should enable SSR for all of your federation projects (e. g. the shell and the micro frontends).

After reading that, is our requirement not feasible or is there another possibility?

Comment: Just a note: At this moment (February 2022) the github of module federation mentions this: "because of a bug in Angular Universal 13, SSR is currently not supported for Angular 13."